# How to debug inability to load library `auto-complete`

Tags: package, init-file, auto-complete-mode, load-path

I am a new to Emacs , i downloaded auto-complete , moved it to ~/.emacs.d/plugins/ then modified the .emacs file to look like :

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (file-name-as-directory
                     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/plugins/auto-complete"))\
)

(require 'auto-complete)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)

(ac-config-default)
(custom-set-variables
;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.                                   
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                       
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                           
'(menu-bar-mode nil)
'(package-archives (quote (("melpa" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") ("g\
nu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(custom-set-faces
;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.                                       
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                       
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                           
)
```

when i restart emacs , it displays the following error :

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/zeaksilva/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, auto-complete

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Comment: It is sufficient to do this `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/")` instead of the first three lines.  What's up with this trailing `\\` on line two?

Comment: @Eddy is there a reason you're installing manually, and not with Emacs's package manager? It's an easier way to manage it, especially with later updates.

Comment: @zck ok . i`ve installed it via Emacs's package manager , but how do i activate it , when i try to type something no magic happens ?

Comment: You have to actually call the function.  If you want it to happen automatically, I recommend `company-mode`.

Comment: FWIW - the question is duplicated at [S.O.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26821686/729907).

Comment: How you use a library is a different question from how you load it. If you have a question about how to use `autocomplete` then please post a separate question for that.

Answer (score 2):

Repeating my response at [S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26822197/729907) -

Put `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the beginning of your init file. Or better yet, append `--debug-init` to the command line you use to invoke Emacs. That will open the debugger when the error occurs. But it seems that the file that has `(provide 'autocomplete)` in it, or that file's directory, is not in your `load-path`. When the debugger opens, use `C-h v load-path`, and see whether it is correct. If not, correct it.

In sum, to be loaded by `require`, the library needs to be `provide`d, and its location needs to be in your `load-path`. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(defconst additional-lisp-dir (expand-file-name "plugins" user-emacs-directory))
(add-to-list 'load-path additional-lisp-dir)
;; Add subdirs to load-path
(let ((default-directory additional-lisp-dir))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

This way you'll add only the top level directory and subdirs will be added automatically

Moreover, why do you install packages manually and not via package-list-packages?

Comment: FWIW - "Installing" a package by putting it in your `load-path` and using `require` is no more "manual" than is invoking `package-list-packages` and "installing" it using that UI.  It's just a different manual method of loading. One can even argue that it is a simpler and more direct way to load (you tell Emacs to load it, and from where). `package.el` could be considered simpler, perhaps, if you are *not* going to load it but just rely on autoloads. But if you load it, you load it - nothing magical, and nothing non-manual, about either approach.

Comment: Obviously, your comment is right, Drew. For that I've included the code in my answer. I'm actually use both things: packages installed in 'elpa' dir. + my config in 'lisp' dir (split from init.el)

Comment: Ah, now I see, that the title of this question was changed significantly by Drew, so his answer suits now better